# unix message queue

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue, unix

Is there an ipc option to get the last message in message queue but not removing it?

I want this to allow many clients reading same messages from the same server..

Edit:
Server and clients are on the same machine!

Thanks

Comment: If you have multiple clients reading the same message from the same queue without dequeuing, can we assume you've worked out a way to remove the message after the last client has accessed it?

Comment: You are probably looking for an Enterprise Queuing system with a Publish/Subscribe implementation. Have a look at ActiveMQ or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to do that using either system v or POSIX message queues. Furthermore, AFAIK neither API allows you to send messages to a remote machine, so unless your clients are running on the same host as the server, you will need to use a higher-level technology.